# Fix some CSS for OL and for link colors

Tags: html, css

I am trying to update this code to get the Ordered list show numbers with boxes like in the right div (for elements 2 and 4).

Also, i would like to know if it is possible to get a colored box under the active link, that remains colored until an other link is selected.

So how can i do this ?

Thx a lot

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
h3 {font-weight: 600; margin: 0 0 10px;}
.colsa .cola-12 {width: 50%; float: left;}
ol li {list-style-type:decimal;}
ol li, ol li a {display: block; line-height: 40px; }
ol li a {padding: 5px 20px 10px; text-decoration: none;}
ol li a:hover a:active {background-color: #ccf;}
.itema {display: none;}
.itema:target {display: block;}
.download-ok .fiche-esp .titrecroch {
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
width: 100%;
}
.fiche-esp .titrecroch {
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
}
h2, h3, .sidebar-all .widget-title, .titrecroch {
font-size: 20px;
}
.small {
font-size: 16px;}
.titrecroch {
color: #000 !important;
font-weight: bold;
    }
.itema h2::before, h3::before, .sidebar-all .widget-title::before, .titrecroch::before {
color: #fcc200;
content: "[";
font-family: "ralewaylight";
font-size: 31px;
font-weight: normal;
padding-right: 8px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.itema h2::after, h3::after, .sidebar-all .widget-title::after, .titrecroch::after {
color: #fcc200;
content: "]";
font-family: "ralewaylight";
font-size: 31px;
font-weight: normal;
padding-left: 8px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.ffpmap .titrecroch {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.flipbook .titrecroch, .formpedago .titrecroch, .galleriepedago .titrecroch {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.orange::before {
background: #eb5d0b none repeat scroll 0 0;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #fff;
content: ">";
font-family: "ralewaylight";
margin-right: 10px;
padding: 7px 10px;
}
.vert::before {
background: #88a137 none repeat scroll 0 0;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #fff;
content: ">";
font-family: "ralewaylight";
margin-right: 10px;
padding: 6px 9px;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
box-sizing: inherit;
}
.cola-12 p {
border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
color: #000;
display: block;
padding: 10px 0;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
margin-left: 2em; 
 text-indent: -2em;
}
.bs {
font-weight: 900;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="colsa">
<div class="cola-12">
<span class="titrecroch">right title</span>
<ol>
  <a href="#itema-1"><li>title 1</li></a>
  <a href="#itema-2"><li>title 2</li></a>
  <a href="#itema-3"><li>title 3</li></a>
  <a href="#itema-4"><li>title 4</li></a>
  <a href="#itema-5"><li>title 5</li></a>
  <a href="#itema-6"><li>title 6</li></a>
  <a href="#itema-7"><li>title 7</li></a>
  </ol>
 </div>

<div class="cola-12">
 <div class="itema" id="itema-1">
  <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 1</span></h3>text 1
 </div>
 <div class="itema" id="itema-2">
  <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 2</span></h3>general text
   <p class="orange">text 2.1</p>
   <p class="orange">text 2.2</p>
   <p class="orange">text 2.3</p>
 </div>
<div class="itema" id="itema-3">
 <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 3</span></h3>text 3 paragraph 1<br/>text 3 paragraph 2
 </div>
 <div class="itema" id="itema-4">
 <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 4</span></h3>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 1: Title 4.1</span> text 4.1</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 2: Title 4.2</span> text 4.2</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 3: Title 4.3</span> text 4.3</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 4: Title 4.4</span> text 4.4.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 5: Title 4.5</span> text 4.5.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 6: Title 4.6</span> text 4.6.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 7: Title 4.7</span> text 4.7.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 8: Title 4.8</span> text 4.8.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 9: Title 4.9</span> text 4.9.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 10: Title 4.10</span> text 4.10.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 11: Title 4.11</span> text 4.11.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="itema" id="itema-5">
   <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 5</span></h3><a href="doc.jpg">Text5</a>
 </div>
 <div class="itema" id="itema-6">
   <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 6</span></h3> text 6
 </div>
 <div class="itema" id="itema-7">
   <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 7</span></h3>
   </div> 
   </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question *(note multiple questions in a single post is not recommended on SO)* - CSS counters could do that.

*Note: your current HTML is invalid. `ol` and `ul` can only have `li` as direct children.*

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
}
li:before {
  content: "[" counter(my-awesome-counter)"]";
  padding-right: 1em;
  color: gold;
}
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

For your second question, you will need javascript. There are a number of existing questions on this to be found by searching SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code, using jquery just for the active link:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loruit/2am7d5n7/5/)

```js
$("ol li").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($(".active").length) {
    $("ol li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
  else {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
h3 {font-weight: 600; margin: 0 0 10px;}
.colsa .cola-12 {width: 50%; float: left;}
ol li {list-style-type:decimal;}
ol li, ol li a {display: block; line-height: 40px; }
ol li a {padding: 5px 20px 10px; text-decoration: none;}
ol li a:hover a:active {background-color: #ccf;}
.itema {display: none;}
.itema:target {display: block;}
.download-ok .fiche-esp .titrecroch {
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
width: 100%;
}
.fiche-esp .titrecroch {
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
}
h2, h3, .sidebar-all .widget-title, .titrecroch {
font-size: 20px;
}
.small {
font-size: 16px;}
.titrecroch {
color: #000 !important;
font-weight: bold;
    }
.itema h2::before, h3::before, .sidebar-all .widget-title::before, .titrecroch::before {
color: #fcc200;
content: "[";
font-family: "ralewaylight";
font-size: 31px;
font-weight: normal;
padding-right: 8px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.itema h2::after, h3::after, .sidebar-all .widget-title::after, .titrecroch::after {
color: #fcc200;
content: "]";
font-family: "ralewaylight";
font-size: 31px;
font-weight: normal;
padding-left: 8px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.ffpmap .titrecroch {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.flipbook .titrecroch, .formpedago .titrecroch, .galleriepedago .titrecroch {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.orange::before {
background: #eb5d0b none repeat scroll 0 0;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #fff;
content: ">";
font-family: "ralewaylight";
margin-right: 10px;
padding: 7px 10px;
}
.vert::before {
background: #88a137 none repeat scroll 0 0;
border-radius: 2px;
color: #fff;
content: ">";
font-family: "ralewaylight";
margin-right: 10px;
padding: 6px 9px;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
box-sizing: inherit;
}
.cola-12 p {
border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
color: #000;
display: block;
padding: 10px 0;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out 0s;
margin-left: 2em; 
 text-indent: -2em;
}
.bs {
font-weight: 900;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 1px #FCC200 solid;
}

ol li {
  border-bottom: 1px #EDEDED solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colsa">
<div class="cola-12">
<span class="titrecroch">right title</span>
<ol>
  <a href="#itema-1"><li id="#itema-1">title 1</li></a>
  <a href="#itema-2"><li id="#itema-2">title 2</li></a>
  <a href="#itema-3"><li id="#itema-3">title 3</li></a>
  <a href="#itema-4"><li id="#itema-4">title 4</li></a>
  <a href="#itema-5"><li id="#itema-5">title 5</li></a>
  <a href="#itema-6"><li id="#itema-6">title 6</li></a>
  <a href="#itema-7"><li id="#itema-7">title 7</li></a>
  </ol>
 </div>

<div class="cola-12">
 <div class="itema" id="itema-1">
  <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 1</span></h3>text 1
 </div>
 <div class="itema" id="itema-2">
  <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 2</span></h3>general text
   <p class="orange">text 2.1</p>
   <p class="orange">text 2.2</p>
   <p class="orange">text 2.3</p>
 </div>
<div class="itema" id="itema-3">
 <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 3</span></h3>text 3 paragraph 1<br/>text 3 paragraph 2
 </div>
 <div class="itema" id="itema-4">
 <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 4</span></h3>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 1: Title 4.1</span> text 4.1</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 2: Title 4.2</span> text 4.2</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 3: Title 4.3</span> text 4.3</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 4: Title 4.4</span> text 4.4.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 5: Title 4.5</span> text 4.5.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 6: Title 4.6</span> text 4.6.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 7: Title 4.7</span> text 4.7.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 8: Title 4.8</span> text 4.8.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 9: Title 4.9</span> text 4.9.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 10: Title 4.10</span> text 4.10.</p>
   <p class="vert"><span class="bs">EO 11: Title 4.11</span> text 4.11.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="itema" id="itema-5">
   <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 5</span></h3><a href="doc.jpg">Text5</a>
 </div>
 <div class="itema" id="itema-6">
   <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 6</span></h3> text 6
 </div>
 <div class="itema" id="itema-7">
   <h3>result - <span class="small">Step 7</span></h3>
   </div> 
   </div> 
  </div>
```